# Codeigniter 3 Autocomplete response slow?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Why using CI 3 the response it is very slow (> 3 Second) to get the json data by using jquery autocomplete. im already test my application with similar code using CI 2 but it only takes respond in shortly 1 Second even less.

here my code (jquery) :

```
 autocomplete: {
                source: function(request, response) {
                 $.ajax({  url : "<?php echo site_url();?>/area/kode_area_tag",
                 data: { query : request.term},
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function(data){
                 response(data);
                 list_data = data;

                 } 

                 });
             },
             minLength: 4
        }
```

and my server side code :

```
function kode_area_tag()
    {
        $list = array();
        $post = trim($this->input->post('query'));


        $sql = "SELECT nama from area where nama like '%$post%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            array_push($list, $row->nama);
        }



        echo json_encode($list);
    }
```

is it my code or codeigniter itself ?
does anyone can give some suggestion ?
thanks

Comment: as additional i try to use pdo driver too but badly nothing difference and as info im using view in database to gain performance before doing those test.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours, searching for this problem.  i think its the problem of the database configuration. 
I should set the parameter -> pconnect : TRUE